# What should I check if the model has extremely good score for both train and test?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I'm using random forest to do binary classification, test size 0.3, 5-fold cv, for both train and test, precision and recall are over 99%, am I over-fitting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done a 70-30 train test split and a 5 fold CV only on the train set. after that got a 99% precision and recall on the TEST set you have covered all the steps.

what you may validate is the proportion of data distribution in your test and train split. 
do a mean on your y_train and y_test. validate that you get comparable numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Check that samples from train and test data sets are different, and possibly try to run on some new real-world samples.